# solving the number of boys who are left handed

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> In a group of 45 children, 60 percent of the children are boys, and 60 percent of the children are left-handed.

If I want to solve the number of boys who are left handed then will it not be 
 $$60\% \times 60\%  \times 45$$

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: This question is not well defined. You need to ask something along the lines of "What is the maximal/minimal possible number of boys who are left handed?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is the following: You can tell two things from the given statement:

- There are $60\% \cdot 45 = 27$ boys in the group.
- There are $60\% \cdot 45 = 27$ left-handed children.

But you are not given any information about the overlapping, that is how many of the boys are left handed. All you can say, is:

- At most $27$ boys are left-handed (there are not more boys).
- At least $9$ boys are left-handed (cause there are $18$ girls only, if they are all left-handed, we need $9$ more left-handed children).

Comment: You can probably also say that the number of left-handed boys is likely to be an integer (so not $16.2$)